# Regex to Make Sure One of Four Letters Appear Only Once

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to only allow the following letters: "uldr" and each one can only appear once. The order that they appear does not matter, its just that only those letters are allowed and they can't repeat. For example

VALID:

uldr

u

ld

rdu

INVALID:

uldrr

uu

ll

dd

drdd

So far this is what I have: `[uldr]{1,4}` but this is allowing the characters to repeat.

Comment: Other tools are more suitable for this job than regex. What language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex `[uldr]{1,4}` will only restrict the characters you are allowing and the length constraint. Besides that you can use a negative look ahead to reject matches where any of the character repeats itself using this negative look ahead `(?!.*(.).*\1)` and your modified regex that you can use is this,

```
^(?!.*(.).*\1)[uldr]{1,4}$
```

**[Demo1](https://regex101.com/r/fi5Gro/1)**

A more optimized regex would be this, but slightly less readable though.

```
^(?![uldr]*([uldr])[uldr]*\1)[uldr]{1,4}$
```

**[Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/fi5Gro/2)**